# Numerical integration of oscillatory integrand

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, numerics

Having two points $\vec{r_1}$ and $\vec{r_2}$ I interested in calculating the following integral
$\int_{0}^{\infty} exp(-ar)r_1r_2dr_1dr_2d\phi_1d\phi_2$,
where

$r = |r_1-r_2| = \sqrt{r_1^2+r_2^2-2r_1r_2cos(\phi_1-\phi_2)}$ is the distance between points. By putting the coordinate system origin to the position of one of points, this integral can be easily calculated:

`(4Pi^2)Integrate[Exp[-a*r]^2 r, {r, 0, Infinity}, Assumptions -> a > 0]`

with the answer `(Pi^2)/(a^2)`. Now if consider the origin of the coordinate system  in some other point and performing numerical integration I expect to get the result close to that:

```
resNumerical = Table[
  NIntegrate[
   Exp[-2 a Sqrt[(r1^2 + r2^2 - 2 r1*r2*Cos[\[Phi]1 - \[Phi]2])]] r1*r2,
   {r1, 0, Infinity},
   {r2, 0, Infinity},
   {\[Phi]1, 0, 2 \[Pi]},
   {\[Phi]2, 0, 2 \[Pi]},
   MinRecursion -> 3],
  {a, 1, 3, 0.5}]
```

which I get `(* {4283.66, 553.123, 311.001, 193.66, 132.923} *)`. These are much bigger numbers than

```
In[1]:= resAnalytical = Table[Pi^2/a^2, {a, 1, 3, 0.5}]
Out[1]= {9.8696, 4.38649, 2.4674, 1.57914, 1.09662}
```

My question is am I doing something wrong with numerical integration?
Any help will be appreciated,
Thank you

Comment: There is something wrong with your analytical result. Look at the dimensions. Assume $r_i$ has a dimension of length (L). Your original formula has therefore the dimension $L^4$. But the analytical integral has the dimension $L^2$.

Comment: angles $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ are dimensionless therefore the formula has also a dimension of $L^2$

Comment: @DavidBaghdasaryan Your derivation of the analytical integral formula seems to be improper: In the complete integral you vary r2 whereas in the analytical formula you fix `r2==0`

Comment: @UlrichNeumann, yes because I put the origin in the position of one of the points and using that integrand depends on the distance between points moved to $r$ integration instead of $r_1$, $r_2$, but this is just selecting the origin of coordinates, the integral should not depend on the origin, right?

Comment: @DavidBaghdasaryan The integral is obviously divergent. What do you want to get from it?

Comment: If you set r2 to zero, then the integral will be zero...

Comment: @DavidBaghdasaryan No, setting one point to the origin  has no effect because the variation of r2 remains!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I see, thank you